# Understanding Result on Non-Degenerate Critical Points

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology, morse-theory

I read a result in a collected works of Steven Smale and one result leapt out at me which I'm clearly not understanding.  Stated:

> Theorem 1.1 (a):  Suppose $J: M \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^2$ function, satisfies property (C) (see below), is bounded from below, and $M$ is a complete Riemannian manifold.  Then the non-degenerate critical points of $J$ are isolated, and if on $J^{a,b}=J^{-1}[a,b]$ for $a,b$ finite, the critical points are non-degenerate, then the critical points of $J$ are finite in number.

And

> Property (C) If $S$ is a subset of $M$ on which $|J|$ is bounded, but on which $\|J'(x)\|$ is not bounded away from zero, then there is a critical point of $J$ in the closure of $S$.

([Source](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BigUKkT1S4UC&pg=PA512&lpg=PA512&dq=finite%20non-degenerate%20critical%20points&source=bl&ots=Y5u4sOEs-q&sig=oEslxXsohuGG47O92DB0s49HU1o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KaJLVaC5Je_LsATthYGoBA&ved=0CFAQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=finite%20non-degenerate%20critical%20points&f=false).)

My question is how do I reconcile that with the function

$$J(x) = \int_0^x t^3 \cdot sin(1/t) dt$$

(where $J'(0)$ is defined to be zero.)  As $x^3sin(1/x)$ on $[0,1]$ is $C^1$, bounded, and I believe satisfies (C), as I understand it the above theorem should say that the set of non-degenerate critical points of $J$ are finite on $J^{-1}[-1,1]$ which I don't believe they are.

Somewhere I'm clearly missing something, likely foolish, but any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just noticed you said $x^3\sin(1/x)$ is $C^1$ but above you required $C^2$.  Is that a typo?  Or the source of the confusion?

Comment: $x^3 sin(1/x)$ is $C^1$ so its integral $J$ should be $C^2$.  I basically just tried to create an example of a $C^2$ function with infinite critical points by integrating a $C^1$ function with infinite zeroes. Clearly I've broken something here, I'm just new enough to the subject that I'm unfortunately not sure what...

Comment: The "if" on the second to last line in the first text shaded in beige is dangling. Maybe something is missing there.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter  Ah OK, the original was worded unituitively.  I've fixed the quote it.  I suppose then that yields the contradiction too as then $0 \in J^{-1}[-1,1]$ is degenerate.  Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

The point $0$ is a degenerate critical point, which you can verify by computing the second derivative.